# Prompt to activate user's account and redirect him to another page

Tags: django

I write a control function `activate` to confirm the User's email and his activating code.

```
def activate(request, a_code):
    """
    Activate User's Account by code from his email.
    """
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(activatecode__code=a_code)
        user.is_active = True
        context = {}
        return render(request, "user/success.html", context)
        time.sleep(5)
        return redirect("/")
    except DoesNotExist:
        context = {}
        return render(request, "user/failure.html", context)
```

After the User successfully activate his account, he will be redirected to the homepage.
Nevertheless, double `return`s did not work properly as I intended.

How to deal with such a context?

Comment: that's not how function works... when you write return statement no other statement execute

Comment: you may use httpresponseredirect for such purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of double return which will not work since second return never reached, you can add javascript redirect to the success template, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157771/redirecting-the-django-built-in-logout-view-after-successfull-logout):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "/";
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Also you probably can try to use [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/) for messages rendering.

Answer (score 0):

```
user = User.objects.get(activatecode__code=a_code)
user.is_active = True
context = {}
return render(request, "user/success.html", context) # First
time.sleep(5)
return redirect("/") # Second
```

Your codes after the first return statement is `unreachable`. Once you have returned from a function, the execution cursor returns to the caller, any code after that will not be executed.

Thus in your case `sleep` and second `return` is never executed.

If you want to redirect the user then you can simply use `redirect()`

Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that when the method runs and evaluates the first return, this ends thread execution of this method that is the instructions are after the first return never will be evaluated why don't you can redirection `def activate(request, a_code): """ Activate User's Account by code from his email. """ try: user = User.objects.get(activatecode__code=a_code) user.is_active = True context = {} return render(request, "user/success.html", context)`

Your code ends here